# Client Program unable to connect with Web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webservice-client

I have a web service application http://localhost:49804/Service1.asmx and I'm able to call methods using a C# application successfully.

Later I have hosted the same Web service on IIS (http://localhost/MyFirstWebService/Service1.asmx) and I'm able to use with Web page(http put/get).

Now I have updated web service reference to http://localhost/MyFirstWebService/Service1.asmx in my C# application.
Now If I call same method I'm getting Exception:

```
An endpoint configuration section for contract 'ServiceReference1.Service1Soap' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.
```

I have googled for this issue and I realize I need to add a client and web bindings in my web.config file. So I have added below part, But that doesn't solve the problem.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
    <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.3/MyFirstWebService/Service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="ClassABC" bindingConfiguration ="httpBinding"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_IABC" />
  </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Looks like I missed binding here in my web server application ?
Hw can I solve this problem, any reference or links to where I should start or any example application will be great help. Do I need to change anything in my Web Service or web.config file changes should be enough ?

Comment: Don't Google, read first: _"more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found"_. Your client has two endpoints configured who are referencing the same contract.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one binding inside `<configuration><system.serviceModel><bindings>`, then you need to pick one by name and pass it to the constructor of your web service client to eliminate the ambiguity.

For example:

```
var svcClientObj = new CustomWebSvcClient("BasicHttpBinding_ICustomWebSvc_OverHttp");
```

Comment: If you have more than one binding configured and you only need one, you need to remove the others. Your suggestion is a workaround for a different problem altogether.

Comment: @CodeCaster: in most cases, you are likely right. However we must assume there are some legitimate reasons for having multiple bindings, otherwise Microsoft would not have built the above overload of the constructor. Perhaps programmatic substitution based on current environment.

Comment: _"we must assume there are some legitimate reasons for having multiple bindings"_ - there are, but not likely for OP's case.